# How to ignore css property by override (bootstrap 3)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap css there is the following:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

I want to ignore the `height:50px` so that it becomes:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left; 
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

But I don't want to modify the bootstrap css itself. Instead I want to override it. What do I override it with? I tried:

```
.navbar-brand {
  height:100%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height:ignore;
}
```

None of these work.

I also have another:

.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
  .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
    width: auto;
  }

When I get rid of the above, things look okay. How do I override this one to behave as if it was deleted?

Comment: How about `height:auto`?

Comment: What do you want the height to be...

Comment: Add your own CSS class, preferably in your own stylesheet. If it's not working, try sticking `!important` inside the declaration.

Comment: @Lee `important` usually means you haven't got the specificity right. It's a crutch and should be used **only** after *every* other avenue has been exhausted....and even then reviewed regularly. **tl/dr** Don't use important.

Comment: I do not know, I just know that I when I get rid of height:50px, things look okay! So I I just want height to be not specified or whatever the "Default" behavior if height was never specified is. I have no height I want to "override" anything to, !important does nothing for me when I have nothing to put !important next to.

Comment: as pangloss mentioned I believe the default is height auto

Comment: You are loading your custom CSS after the Bootstrap CSS, right?

Comment: @Rolando The "default" behaviour you are talking about, you have to find it by going up (down in the window) the DOM tree when in Chrome Dev Tools / Elements. Or you can take a look at the "calculated" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp), the default height value when it's not specified is `auto`.

So, you only need to override it using this value.